# Using maxIdle and minIdle time Connection Properties in JBoss/WildFly

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly

we are in the process of porting our configuration from Tomcat to WildFly. Within our Tomcat connection pool configuration we are using **maxIdle** and **minIdle** properties, which as the doc say:

> maxIdle    (int) The maximum number of connections that should be kept
>   in the pool at all times. Default value is maxActive:100 Idle
>   connections are checked periodically (if enabled) and connections that
>   been idle for longer than minEvictableIdleTimeMillis will be released.
>   (also see testWhileIdle)
>
> minIdle    (int) The minimum number of established connections that
>   should be kept in the pool at all times.

Looking at JBoss/WildFly docs, the only available parameter is **idle-timeout-minutes**, which refers anyway to a single connection idle time:

> The maximum time, in minutes, before an idle
>   connection is closed. A value of 0 disables timeout. Defaults to 15
>   minutes.

Is there a workaround to mimic the same configuration also on JBoss/WildFly ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat uses both a **minIdle** and **maxIdle** parameter to determine respectively the minimum and maximum of idle connections that should be kept in the pool. While the **minIdle** parameter, can be turned to be WildFly **min-pool-size**, on the other hand, the **maxIdle** parameter has not corresponding match on WildFly. The closest match is the **idle-timeout-minutes**, which is the number of minutes after which unused connections are closed (default 15 minutes). You can actually vary this parameter let’s say to 10 minutes as follows:

```
/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS/:write-attribute(name=idle-timeout-minutes,value=10)
```

Source: [From Tomcat to WildFly in one day](http://www.itbuzzpress.com/ebooks/from-tomcat-to-wildfly.html)